# yii2 : layout of error not work

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have site with rbac roles and when i get error for not access to some pages i get white page with error.

use these codes for had layout but didn't work true:

my siteControlle:

```
 public function actionError()
{
    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
    if ($exception !== null) {
        $this->layout = 'main';
        return $this->render('error', ['exception' => $exception]);
    }
}
```

i have this function in sitecontroller and i think problem for this:

```
 public function actions() {

    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',

        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
    ];
}
```

main.php:

```
'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
```

error. php  view page

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = $name;
?>
<div class="site-error">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <?= nl2br(Html::encode($message)) ?>
</div>

<p>
    The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
</p>
<p>
    Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.
</p>
```

i test my web with other error and i understand that other errors show in my view layout truely but just access error not in layout

Comment: where you put your layout php. may be issue in your path . show your directory structure

Answer (score 0):

In setup like yours method actionError() in your site controller is never called, because you declared error in method actions(), comment following lines:

```
       'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
```

in your site controller and you should see your error, looking at your view you must pass values for name and message properties, something like this:

```
public function actionError() {
    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
    if ($exception !== null) {
        $this->layout = 'main';
        return $this->render('error', ['name' => $exception->getCode(), 'message' => $exception->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

Of course site/error must be available in browser (setup rules in controller and paths on file system as needed).

Comment: error is not in code , but there is issue in path,  and error class is defined in main.php  in config ,not in action

Comment: @vladimir thank you for your solution but i don't know how setup reulws in controller can you say?

Comment: @YasinPatel  yes you are right that errorAction path is defined in config/main.php but if you leave 'error' block  in site/actions that means that actionError in site controller is never called, because  there is 'error' declaration in site/actions (standalone action as yii\web\ErrorAction), so if user wants to bypass  this routing you don't change main.php  only comment(or delete) declaration. You can see controller lifecycle here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html. And after all I did say that paths must be set correctly.

Comment: @tara Do you have (frontend/backend)/site/error.php file? Can it be read by your web server?

Comment: @vladimir yes i have this file and i don't know how can know this is read by web server or not. i comment those lines you say but not diffrent

Comment: @vladimir i test my web with other error and i understand that other errors show in my view layout truely but just access error not in layout

Comment: @tara access error as forbidden for user that isn't logged or doesn't have appropriate rights?